# why Hibernate OneToMany mapping has to explicit refresh entity to make it work in unit test

Tags: spring, hibernate, one-to-many

It takes me hours to figure out such surprising behaviour when do test on OneToMany mapping.
I rerea        @Entity
d the hibernate guide, double check the code, test deisgn, and finally find out the root cause may be related with hibernate cache design.
Here is the code excerpt:

```
@Entity
public class Organization {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cooperation_id")
private Cooperation cooperation;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="organization_id", nullable=true)
private Organization upperLevel;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="upperLevel")
private Collection<Organization> subOrganizations = new ArrayList<Organization>();

@OneToOne(mappedBy="organization")
private TimeoffSetting timeoffSetting;

private String name;
...
```

The JUNIT test:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager

@Transactional
public void organization() {
    Organization organization_it = new Organization(cooperation, "IT");
    organization_it.setUpperLevel(organizationTop);
    organization_it = organizationRepository.save(organization_it);

    Organization organization_hr = new Organization(cooperation, "HR");
    organization_hr.setUpperLevel(organizationTop);
    organization_hr = organizationRepository.save(organization_hr);

    Organization organization_unix = new Organization(cooperation, "UNIX");
    organization_unix.setUpperLevel(organization_it);
    organization_unix = organizationRepository.save(organization_unix);

    boolean hasIt = false;
    boolean hasHr = false;
    Iterable<Organization> organizations = organizationRepository.findAll();
    for(Organization o: organizations) {
        entityManager.refresh(o);
        if (o.getName() == "cooperation") {
            org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(o.isTopLevel());
            org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(o.getSubOrganizations().size(), 2);

        }
    ...
```

Please notice the **entityManager.refresh(o)** method call here, if I don't make refresh the entity, the OneToMany mapping test of **assertEquals(getSubOrganizations().size(), 2)**  will cause failure.
By googling the internet, Spring's integration test deserve to be more caution when  writing ORM test.
One artical may be useful [spring pitfalls transactional tests](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple: you assigned IT and HR's `upperLevel` organization, but neglected to maintain the coherence of the object graph by adding IT and HR to the top level's `subOrganizations` list.

It's not really a problem for Hibernate, because you took care of setting the *owner* side of each bidirectional association, and that is all Hibernate needs to persist this association.

But since the objects were not created and populated by Hibernate, but by you, they are what you made them be. As you've noticed by using `refresh()`, the two sides of the association are in coherence when Hibernate is in charge of creating and populating the entities.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I kind of understand what's happened beneath the hibernate. But my intention is that it is not straight forward. And from certain perspective, the integrity in ORM cache is not properly maintained. If it is not such cache layer, I won't run into this. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.